# Mouse pointer stuck and not working properly

Tags: command-line, drivers, dual-boot, server, display

I have a problem with lunar distro.

The mouse pointer is shivering and stuck most of the time. A rboot fix it for 10 min and starts again. Below is my distro details.

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 23.04"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="23.04"
VERSION="23.04 (Lunar Lobster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=lunar
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=lunar
LOGO=ubuntu-logo
```

Dell Vostro is my laptop, this is on dual boot. Windows has no issues.

How can I fix it? Please help